# Designing Address validation for app

Tags: java, street-address

I am planning to design an address validation for users registering in my app. Possibly validating by zipcode and state.

Any idea how to handle addresses from around the globe?

Do i need to insert all the zipcodes in the database and then validate the address. Any possible suggestion for the implementation?

Thanks and Welcome :)
Krisp

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no international standard for zip codes and a list of all zip codes in the world would be out of date before you were finished putting it together, I suggest a smaller approach:

Identify the countries that you will have to handle most and develop seperate validation rules for each of them. Make certain that with this you handle a vast majority of your users (e.g. 95%, or98%). For all the other countries, just accept what they enter vithout further validation.

There are so many different address formats in the world that it is just not worth the effort (if at all possible) to handle them all.

Answer (score 2):

There is MASSIVE variance among address and postal code formats, such that there is not any "standard" way of doing this.  See "[Frank's Compulsive Guide to Postal Addresses](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/postal.html)"...

How much/what kind of validation do you really need?  If the user is entering their shipping address, for example, they're more likely than you to know what particular format their local postal/shipping provider needs.  Just give them a multiline textarea to enter it.  If you need parts of it to calculate shipping costs, request just the information you need (City/Country, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Postal Codes can actually be a headache because in some places they can represent very tiny areas as opposed to the US where they often represent relatively large areas (except in a big city where they may represent a few blocks).

Look at Canada, their postal codes can actually represent very very tiny areas.  Two stores on opposite sides of the street often have different Canadian postal codes.  Also in a list of Canadian businesses, when merging the list it is not uncommon to see the same address with a slightly different postal code.  This just indicates that a lot of people get it wrong.  On a customer basis I don't know how realistic it is that they actually get their exact zip code right.

http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/postal-ca.html

Basically it seems that each apartment or business dwelling may get their own zip code, which would make sense based upon what I have seen with Canadian business addresses.

The other point is that this is just Canada.  Each European country will have its own address/postal code, so will Australia, Russia, etc...  If you really want to do address verification, this is a major project.

To actually verify the address you need to to verify the postal code, city, and street.  In the US the census releases the TIGER database files which often have a list of streets.  But for other countries I don't know how you can get a list of streets.  It may be best to look into a commercial package (maybe one of the GIS packages, although a lot of them only offer detailed addresses for the US/Canada and sometimes a few European countries).

Answer (score 0):

A perfect Address validation can't be exactly placed in the already developed application, the validation of zip-code / postal code can be done as per the name of country though.

Please check the regex from the '[supplementalData.xml](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/tags/release-2-0-1/common/supplemental/postalCodeData.xml)' xml file from the source [xml-files source](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/tags/release-2-0-1/common/supplemental).
By parsing the xml you can find the corresponding postal-code regular expression for the country-code passed at the run-time, where you can check whether it's matching with country.

Answer (score 0):

Have found another answer on this :
please refer the *wiki*'s link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes.

Here you can find most of the zip-code patterns of most of the countries, of which you may write regex and maintain into database, which would help you to validate zip-code easily and also an optimized approach !

Answer (score 0):

As many users have mentioned previously, verifying international addresses is basically impossible because there are no standards across countries and many countries don't have the resources for their postal system.  Technically speaking, even in the United States, the USPS is struggling.

On a minimum you can offer address verification on a per-country basis.  One of the easiest countries where you get a lot of coverage is in the USA.  To do this you need to connect to some kind of address verification web service.  There are several companies which have web services for this.  One thing to be careful of is ensuring that each provider has geo-distribution of their API to ensure that any outages on their part don't flow back to you and kill your application.  Beyond that, just make sure the results are CASS certified.

In the interest of full disclosure, I'm the founder of SmartyStreets.  We have an [address verification web service API](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) called LiveAddress.  You're more than welcome to contact me personally if you have any questions.